# How to work with CellValidating

Tags: c#, winforms

I got stuck with this matter, so I ask for your help

You know, I have a datagridview with two columns code and name. I want to input data to the gridview and check if code is duplicated. Tried  to use cellvalidating but I always got the empty code although I entered some values.

`string value = datagridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();`

If I use CellEndEdit I can catch the value but the cell is lost focus that is not what I need.

Please help !

Thanks

Comment: You can store current cell info in some varibale like cell-index, row-index when that cell gets focus using some proper event, that way when your current cell lose focus, you will have old cell-index/row-index values.

Comment: What's `DataSource` of your `DataGridView`?